# jQuery mobile popups closing unexpectedly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, popup

I'm building a site based on jQuery mobile, with the following script versions.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

I've got an issue with a popup, displayed by the following code.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(){
    if(onPgLd==true){
        onPgLd=false;
        $("#globPageLoad").popup("open");
    };
});
```

The popup opens as I'd expect, but then immediately closes again.
The only other event-triggered code I have is inside a pagecreate block, which I understood completes prior to pagecontainershow.
Is there an event that happens post-pagecontainershow, or is something else happening?
(I even added ' data-dismissible="false" ' to the off-chance it would make a difference. It didn't...)
I've only been able to test the site on Chrome (laptop and mobile).
Any ideas?

after looking at comments below, none the wiser. The fiddle works exactly as I'd want, but I can't see programmatically where it's different to my code - the .enhancewithin() is called during pagecreate, and the pop up looks exactly as I'd hope.

I tried amending the function to this;

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(event){
    console.log("pagecontainershow");
    //event.stopPropagation();
    if(onPgLd==true){
        onPgLd=false;
        $( "#globPageLoad" ).bind({
            popupafteropen: function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                console.log("popupafteropen");
            }
        });
        $("#globPageLoad").popup("open");
        console.log("popup open");
    };
});
```

Everything logs in the order I'd expect it to, but the popup still disappears.
Another clue (I think?) is that the url remains suffixed by "#&ui-state=dialog", which makes me think this is a glitch as the popup is not being closed intentionally by jQuery?

Comment: The event is bubbling up and closing it.  (Probably need e.stopPropagation()) JSBin is made for these kinds of questions.  Make a bin for it and you'll get a much better answer.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with a working popup to get you started. Update it with your issue if you would like further help. https://jsfiddle.net/mr3ducv8/